# Generating a sinewave on Matlab with specific harmonics

Tags: matlab, sine, fft

I need to generate a sinewave on Matlab so I can use the generated values, I need 1000 samples per cycle for grid simulation using micro-controller. I was able to generate a pure sinewave and it is working fine. Now, I need to generate distorted sinewaves for example, a signal with 9% from U_1 in the 5th harmonics.

I am trying this code:

```
f=50; %frequency of sine wave
overSampRate=200; %oversampling rate
fs=overSampRate*f; %sampling frequency
nCyl = 5; %to generate five cycles of sine wave
t=0:1/fs:nCyl*1/f; %time base
phase = 0;
x1=1*sin(2*pi*f*t+phase) + 0.09*sin(2*pi*f*5*t+phase);
```

But when I perform fft using this code, the values at h5 don't seem correct:

```
L=length(x1);        
NFFT=2^10;       
X=fft(x1,NFFT);       
Px=X.*conj(X)/(NFFT*L); %Power of each freq components       
fVals=fs*(0:NFFT/2-1)/NFFT;     
figure(2);
plot(fVals,Px(1:NFFT/2),'b','LineSmoothing','on','LineWidth',1);         
title('One Sided Power Spectral Density');       
xlabel('Frequency (Hz)')         
ylabel('PSD');
```

Any idea where I might be wrong?

Comment: We cannot see the incorrect values ... where are they ? is there a plot ?

Answer (score 1):

Don't use 1024 point for your FFT because you won't get the value for 50Hz and 250Hz : fVals = 0, 9.7656, 19.5313, 29.2969, 39.0625, 48.8281, 58.5938...

I also suggest to use amplitude spectrum instead of power spectrum :

````
f=50; %frequency of sine wave
overSampRate=200; %oversampling rate
fs=overSampRate*f; %sampling frequency
nCyl = 5; %to generate five cycles of sine wave
t=0:1/fs:nCyl*1/f; %time base
phase = 0;
x1=1*sin(2*pi*f*t+phase) + 0.09*sin(2*pi*f*5*t+phase);

L=length(x1); 
NFFT = L-1;
X = fft(x1,NFFT);
X2 = abs(X/NFFT);
X1 = X2(1:NFFT/2+1);
X1(2:end-1) = 2*X1(2:end-1);

ff = fs*(0:(NFFT/2))/NFFT;
plot(ff,X1) 
xlim([0 500])
title('Single-Sided Amplitude Spectrum of x_1(t)')
xlabel('f (Hz)')
ylabel('|X_1(f)|')

```
````